# Remove plugin information from the plugins page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook-wordpress

I want to remove the information about an installed plugin from the WordPress dashboard plugins page. I have written the following code, but it doesn't work!

please guide me?

```
add_filter( 'all_plugin', 'remove_plugins');

function remove_plugins($plugins)

{
 if(is_plugin_active('/woocommerce-checkout-manager/woocommerce-checkout-manager.php')) {

 unset( $plugins['woocommerce-checkout-manager.php'] );

}
 return $plugins;

}
```

I added this code to my template function file but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the filter below to delete the information of the plugin installed in WordPress and the WordPress plugins page.

Note that in the first value, put the **folder and the main file** of the plugin, and in the second value, only the main file of the plugin **without adding the folder**.

```
add_filter(
    'all_plugins',
    function ( $plugins ) {

        $shouldHide = ! array_key_exists( 'show_all', $_GET );

        if ( $shouldHide ) {
            $hiddenPlugins = [
                'woocommerce-checkout-manager/woocommerce-checkout-manager.php',
                'woocommerce-checkout-manager.php',
            ];

            foreach ( $hiddenPlugins as $hiddenPlugin ) {
                unset( $plugins[ $hiddenPlugin ] );
            }

        }

        return $plugins;
    }
);
```